# Pass function in props Griddle custom component - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

I have the following code:

```
var RiderComponent = React.createClass({
    updater: function(){
        this.props.metadata.update();
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <a href="#" onClick={this.updater}>
                click!
            </a>
        );
    }
});

var RiderList = React.createClass({
    columnMeta: [
        {
            "columnName": "action",
            "displayName": "",
            "cssClassName": "buy",
            "order": 6,
            "customComponent": RiderComponent,
            "update": this.update
        }
    ],

    update: function () {
        this.props.update();
    },

    render: function () {
        return <Griddle results={this.props.data}
                        useGriddleStyles={false}
                        showFilter={true}
                        columnMetadata={this.columnMeta}
                        columns={['action']}
                        resultsPerPage={18}
                        initialSort={'value'}
                        initialSortAscending={false}
                        noDataMessage={'Geen wielrenners gevonden.'}
        />
    }
});
```

I want to run the update() function from RiderList in my RiderComponent when I click on an item. However I keep getting: 'Uncaught TypeError: this.props.metadata.update is not a function'.

What is the correct way to execute the update function in my RiderComponent?

RiderList is rendered in TeamManager:

```
var TeamManager = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            results: [],
            activeRiders: [],
            extraRiders: [],
            availablePositions: []
        }
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.getExternalData();
    },

    getExternalData: function () {
        var race_id = 1; // TODO: this is hardcoded
        request = Api.getRidersPageUrl(race_id);

        $.get(request, function (rsp) {
            var data = rsp;
            var activeRiders = []; // Riders with position 0..8
            var extraRiders = []; // Riders with position 9..14
            var availablePositions = Array.apply(null, {length: 9}).map(Number.call, Number); // Array 0..8;

            if (data) {
// set data to arrays here
            }

            this.setState({
                results: data,
                activeRiders: activeRiders,
                extraRiders: extraRiders,
                availablePositions: availablePositions
            });
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <RiderList update={this.getExternalData} data={this.state.results}/>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = TeamManager;
```

Here this.getExternalData just reloads the data in this.state.results.

EDIT: I got something working while using onRowClick={this.update} in RiderList render . However this fires when I click the row and not a specific button IN the row.

Comment: we don't even know if you are passing the props properly, can you post the full component?

Comment: the props are passed correctly, when I use "update": "this is a test" and console.log(this.props.metadata.update) it prins the this is a test. However this.update gives me 'undefined'. I edited the main post a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer based upon question new info,

```
var RiderComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <a onClick={this.props.metadata.update}>
                click!
            </a>
        );
    }
});

var RiderList = React.createClass({
    getColumnMeta: function(){
        return[
            {
                "columnName": "action",
                "displayName": "",
                "cssClassName": "buy",
                "order": 6,
                "customComponent": RiderComponent,
                "update": this.update
            }
        ]
    },

update: function () {
    this.props.update();
},

render: function () {
    return <Griddle results={this.props.data}
                    useGriddleStyles={false}
                    showFilter={true}
                    columnMetadata={this.getColumnMeta()}
                    columns={['action']}
                    resultsPerPage={18}
                    initialSort={'value'}
                    initialSortAscending={false}
                    noDataMessage={'Geen wielrenners gevonden.'}
    />
}
});
```

Comment: I added the updater function but on page load I get: Uncaught TypeError: this.updater.bind is not a function

Comment: I guess there is a typo use onClick instead of onclick

Comment: I tried both but doesn't seem to make any difference, got the same error

Comment: hmm... can you provide the whole code for RiderList and TeamManager where RiderList is rendered?

Comment: Griddle component implementation is missing. Can you add that one too? Need to check how update function is passed on to RiderComponent.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if solves your issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that `this.props.metadata` was depreciated in v0.8 and higher. The solution would only work with v0.7. Using v0.7, it would work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/3yem8mq1/6/